# Is $n^7 - 77$ ever a Fibonacci number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, fibonacci-numbers

As the question title suggests, is $n^7 - 77$ ever a Fibonacci number, where $n$ is a integer?

Comment: **Hint:** Consider the sequence of fibonacci numbers modulo $29$.

Comment: @JMoravitz  sorry, but where does 29 come from?

Comment: @GCab one wants a modulus where "to the  $7$" takes few values. So the order of the multiplicative group should be divisible by $7$, and $29$ is the first prime such that $p-1$ is a multiple of $7$.

Comment: @quid thanks, I misunderstood the meaning of "ever"

Answer (score 31):

The fibonacci sequence goes as follows:

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
F_n         &1&1&2&3&5&8&13&21&34&55&89&144&233&377&610&987\\
F_n\pmod{29}&1&1&2&3&5&8&13&21&5 &26&2&28&1&0&1&1\end{array}$

It is clear that the cycle will repeat for $F_n\pmod{29}$ as we reached again a point where it is two ones in a row.

So, the set of possible values modulo $29$ that a fibonacci number can be is $\{0,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,26,28\}$

On the other hand, $n^7\pmod{29}$ can only ever be $0,1,12,17,28$ by fermat's little theorem.

Thus, $n^7-77$ can only ever be one of $\{9,10,11,22,27\}$

We see that the set of possible values of $n^7-77\pmod{29}$ does not intersect the set of possible values of $F_n\pmod{29}$, therefore no solutions exist.